# how to get parameter value from a url using js

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

the link is

```
http://nycs00058260/sites/usitp/_layouts/CreateWebPage_DingDing.aspx?List={74AB081E-59FB-45A5-876D-284607DA03C6}&RootFolder=%3b&Text=%27MDNSO%27
```

how can I parse the parameter "Text"(at the end) from the url using javascript?

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

[URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/) is a small library that makes working with URLs nice and easy :)

```
var url = new URI("http://nycs00058260/sites/usitp/_layouts/CreateWebPage_DingDing.aspx?List={74AB081E-59FB-45A5-876D-284607DA03C6}&RootFolder=%3b&Text=%27MDNSO%27");
var queryMap = URI.parseQuery(url.query());
var text = queryMap["Text"];

console.log("Text: ", text);
```

Comment: ya it's cook, but how can I parse the current URL, not enter it manually, is there a variable of the current url?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine window.location.search : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

with indexOf : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

and substring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring